# Not recieving the notification from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I have an android app in which firebase is integrated.

- i have successfully received the firebase registration id at beginning .

But when i sent the message from firebase console to my app, I am not receiving it in the phone

this is my app gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
```

build gradle

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

i have a separate class MyFirebaseMessagingService  which extends FirebaseMessagingService

```
 public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.e("tagg", "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    if (remoteMessage == null)
        return;

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
            handleDataMessage(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

i am not getting any log in this class.

how is it possible in which part the error is occuring, i have successfully received the reg id , so what can be the error

Comment: Have you try to send message using token (onTokenRefresh) from firebase ?

Comment: when you try to send notification is your app is in foreground ? try sending notification when app is in background

Comment: Please follow this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client for complete integration firebase messaging into android.

Comment: see my answer may be it is due to that if you missed it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the service to your AndroidManifest?

```
     <service
        android:name=".firebase.MyFirebaseInstanceService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the service to your AndroidManifest

```
<service android:name=".YourFirebaseMessagingService">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
     </intent-filter>
 </service>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void HandleNotification(String messagebody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, your.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);



    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.logo)
            .setContentTitle("")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: and call it like handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());